# Equation invalid in conditional formatting

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have a formula that works fine in cells but is marked as invalid when I plug it into conditional formatting; the logic of the equation however is exactly what I need. The formula is as follows:

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(DEALS!$G$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1, 0), "Likes"),   Q2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(DEALS!$F$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1, 0),   R2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(DEALS!$F$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1, 0))`

What must I change in order to make the equation valid for conditional formatting?

Appreciate any help I can get with this!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

green:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!G1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0), "Likes"),       
 NOT(Q2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!F1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0)),       
 NOT(R2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!F1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0)))
```

red:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!G1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0), "Likes"),       
 (Q2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!F1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0)),       
 (R2>=VLOOKUP(H2, INDIRECT("DEALS_RNG"), COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!F1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT("DEALS!A1"))+1, 0)))
```

[image]